# Laravel: Organizing tests into folders and running them

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

Is it possible in Laravel to run unit test based on the folder they're placed in?

Currently, the **phpunit.xml** specifies **/tests** as the root directory for unit testing:

```
...
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
...
```

Test are ran via CLI with `phpunit` command. I would like to organize tests into subfolders, like this:

**/tests**

- **/unit**
- **/integration**

so I can run tests only from the specified subfolder like: `phpunit integration`.

I tried the above, however the framework assumes that "integration" is the name of a PHP file that doesn't exist.

How do I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with Laravel. It's just PHPUnit.

You can define `testsuites` and execute them by name.

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
        <directory>./app/tests/unit/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="integration">
        <directory>./app/tests/integration/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Then run `phpunit --testsuite integration`

Comment: I added those two testsuites to the default one. Now, `phpunit` triggers all tests (root and subfolders). However, `phpunit integration` still thows **Cannot open file "integration.php"**.

Comment: Ouh my bad! You need to run it with `phpunit --testsuite integration`. Updated my answer